# How can I make C++ ADL to look into all instances of a template?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I'm following the *[How to implement a constant-expression counter in C++](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/)* tutorial *and* I'm trying to fix the *[C++14 Reflections Without Macros, Markup nor External Tooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ)* talk limitations.

The basic idea of the tutorial is this:

```
template<int N>
struct flag {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>);
};

template<int N>
struct writer {
   friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>) { return N; }
   static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int N, class = char[noexcept(adl_flag(flag<N> ()))?+1:-1]>
int constexpr reader (int, flag<N>) { return N; }

template<int N>
int constexpr reader (float, flag<N>, int R = reader (0, flag<N-1>())) { return R; }

int constexpr reader (float, flag<0>) { return 0; }

template<int N = 1, int C = reader (0, flag<32> ())>
int constexpr next (int R = writer<C + N>::value) { return R; }

int main () {
  constexpr int a = next ();
  constexpr int b = next ();
  constexpr int c = next ();

  // YES! it works!!!
  static_assert (a == 1 && b == a+1 && c == b+1, "try again");
}
```

Note: If you are not interested by now, it's a good time to stop reading :-)

And the talk explains how to extract number of fields and fields types for POD types using aggregate initialization and implicit conversion operator, but the major limitation is that only primitive types are supported.

I've provided the above background to justify my motivations!

When I combined these two approaches I came to this:

```
template<int N>
struct flag {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>);
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct writer {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>) {
    return N;
  }
  friend constexpr T field_type(flag<N>) { return T{}; }
  static constexpr int value = N;
};
```

The `field_type(flag<N>)` will give me the type of `N`th field.
Note that it's a friend function and for the `N`th field of a `POD` type exactly one `field_type(flag<N>)` will be defined by the compiler.

`g++` gives me `no matching function for call to 'field_type(flag<1>)` for `decltype(field_type(flag<1>))`.

I need to somehow force `ADL` to search in all instances of `writer<T,N>`.
How can I do that?

**Update**

As @T.C.mentioned ADL only looks into associated classes, and `writer` isn't one. (That's why `adl_flag` is declared in `flag` - so that `ADL` could find it.)

How can I make `writer` an associated class without knowing the `T` value so that `ADL` can find it?

Comment: Considering that the committee is going to ban the whole counter thing, I don't see the point in spending time on this.

Comment: In any event, ADL (and this has nothing to do with ODR) only looks into associated classes, and `writer` isn't one. (That's why `adl_flag` is declared in `flag` - so that ADL could find it.)

Comment: @T.C. `the committee is going to ban the whole counter thing` Can please give a reference that indicate that's their intention? The ADL rules that meta-counter uses are old. How committee is going to change the rules without possibly breaking millions of code lines!

Comment: @T.C. Fixed the `ODR` mistake in the last line of question, i meant `ADL` :-)

Comment: [CWG issue 2118](http://wg21.link/CWG2118).

Comment: They can't change the ADL rules, but the counter doesn't just depend on ADL.

Comment: @amin If you give me a complete example in a web compiler like coliru, I could check what's possible. It would be easier to test things with a code that reproduce the error from the start.

Comment: "YES! it works!!!" not in any compiler I've tried. The `noexcept` stuff you added differs from the original post.

Comment: @Barry That's great news :-) I'm so exited to see your solution.

Comment: @Barry That version with `noexcept` is actually the "Workaround for VC++", listed at the end of the linked page.  Try it with [the Visual C++ online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), and it works.  Basically, it compensates for MSVC's spotty implementation of: SFINAE, aggregate initialisation in constant expressions, and re-evaluation of expressions used as both template parameters & function parameter default values in the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `field_type` declaration to flag template, with return type `auto` (only available after C++14)

Only works in gcc 4.9:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
struct flag {
    friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>);
    friend constexpr auto field_type(flag<N>);
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct writer {
    friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>) { return N; }
    friend constexpr auto field_type(flag<N>) { return (T&&)(*(T*)0); }  // remove default constructable restriction
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int N, class = char[noexcept(adl_flag(flag<N> ()))?+1:-1]>
int constexpr reader (int, flag<N>) { return N; }

template<int N>
int constexpr reader (float, flag<N>, int R = reader (0, flag<N-1>())) { return R; }

int constexpr reader (float, flag<0>) { return 0; }

template<typename T, int N = 1, int C = reader (0, flag<32> ())>
int constexpr next (int R = writer<T, C + N>::value) { return R; }

int main () {
    constexpr int a = next<int> ();
    constexpr int b = next<double> ();
    constexpr int c = next<long> ();

    // YES! it works!!!
    static_assert (a == 1 && b == a+1 && c == b+1, "try again");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<1>{})), int>{}, "first is int");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<2>{})), double>{}, "second is double");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<3>{})), long>{}, "third is long");

}
```

Use decltype of auto functions instead of noexcept, works after gcc 5.2, clang 3.5.1 - 3.7.1:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
struct flag {
    constexpr friend auto adl_flag(flag<N>);
    friend auto field_type(flag<N>);
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct writer {
    friend constexpr auto adl_flag(flag<N>) { return 0; }
    friend auto field_type(flag<N>) { return (T&&)(*(T*)0); }
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int N, class = decltype(adl_flag(flag<N>{}))>
int constexpr reader (int, flag<N>) { return N; }

template<int N>
int constexpr reader (float, flag<N>, int R = reader (0, flag<N-1>())) { return R; }

int constexpr reader (float, flag<0>) { return 0; }

template<typename T, int N = 1, int C = reader (0, flag<32> ())>
int constexpr next (int R = writer<T, C + N>::value) { return R; }

int main () {
    constexpr int a = next<int> ();
    constexpr int b = next<double> ();
    constexpr int c = next<long> ();

    // YES! it works!!!
    static_assert (a == 1 && b == a+1 && c == b+1, "try again");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<1>{})), int>{}, "first is int");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<2>{})), double>{}, "second is double");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(field_type(flag<3>{})), long>{}, "third is long");

}
```